# Clear the list in scheme

Tags: list, scheme

```
(define ls2 '((james (1 2 3) (4 5 6) (8 5 6))
              (daren (7 8 9) (2 6 4))
              ))    
(define (delete name lst clear)
      (if (equal? (caar ls2) name) (clear (cdar lst)) 
       (delete name (cdr lst) clear)))

(define (clear lst)
      (if (null? lst) #t (remove (car lst) lst)))

(delete 'james ls2 clear)
```

> If james is matched with an element of list then (1 2 3) (4 5 6) (8 5
>   6) must be clear. I can just clear the (1 2 3) and i want to clear (4
>   5 6) (8 5 6) each by each recursively. However i can't succesive that.
>   I need an emergency help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clear` procedure you wrote won't work, `remove` creates a new list where the removed element isn't present, but the original remains intact. Try this instead:

```
(define (delete name lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((equal? (caar lst) name)        ; if there's a match
         (cons (list (caar lst))         ; clear all elements at once
               (delete name (cdr lst)))) ; and advance recursion
        (else (cons (car lst) 
                    (delete name (cdr lst))))))
```

This is how it works: it creates a new list where the elements are removed, leaving the original list unmodified - that's how we write programs in Scheme:

```
(define lst '((james (1 2 3) (4 5 6) (8 5 6))
              (daren (7 8 9) (2 6 4))))

(delete 'james lst)
=> '((james) (daren (7 8 9) (2 6 4)))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for everything. Your helps make me relief :)